# Can you manually set the SSL cert_store for the Savon client gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate, savon

**Context**

I'm currently trying to get my Savon client to read a peer certificate from the default system SSL cert folder. Basically, the effect I want to produce is calling `set_default_paths` on the Savon client's http cert store.

Essentially, I'm attempting to explicitly set the `cert_store` for a Savon client to `OpenSSL::X509::Store.new` so that I can manually call `set_default_paths` and force it to use the system certificates.

I've been looking through the Savon documentation and while I see that there are ways to pass in certs/keys, there's no obvious way to do this that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
client = Savon.client wsdl:'https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublicV2.asmx?WSDL', convert_request_keys_to: :none
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.set_default_paths
client.globals.ssl_cert_store cert_store
response = client.call :kisi_ve_cuzdan_dogrula, message: message
```